# When is faithfulness transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have found the next statement in a book about separability of algebras.

> Let $V$ be a faithful $S$-module and $T$ an Azumaya algebra with center $S$. If $V$ is also a left $T$-module, then $V$ is faithful as a $T$-module.

I have not been able to prove this statement. Any help would be very useful.

Comment: In the definition of Azumaya algebra, is $T$ locally free over $R$ ?

Comment: In my case $T$ is a finitely generated projective and faithful $R$-module, so is locally free.

Comment: I have just edited the question. I think i already have the answer.

Comment: Then please post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that ${\rm Ann}_T(V)=0.$ It is known that ${\rm Ann}_T(V)$ is a two-sided ideal of $T.$ Since $T$ is central separable with center $S,$ there is a one to one correspondence between the two sided ideals of $T$ and the ideals of $S.$
 In fact Auslander and Goldman in their work  (The Brauer group of a commutative ring), showed that if $I$ is a two sided ideal of $T,$ then $I=\mathfrak{b}T,$  where $\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal of $S$ and $I\cap S=\mathfrak{b}.$  In our case $V$ is a faithfull $S$-module, then ${\rm Ann}_T(V)\cap S=0,$ so it must be ${\rm Ann}_T(V)=0.$